# Where to find the short description within Google Maps API of a location?

Tags: json, google-maps

I'm trying to use Google Maps API to grab information from a location.  At the moment, I'm trying to find the short description that is provided after you search for a location in Google Maps.  For example, if you type in "Golden Gate Park" within the Google Maps, you will see the description for it as "The city's 1,000-ac. oasis draws hikers, bikers, art lovers & music fans. - Google"

I've been using Google Maps API, specifically the place search and place details as shown in the API documentation below.
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

However, when I go and grab the JSON results, I can never find the entry that shows that short little description.  Does anyone know where I can find it?

Comment: Doesn't look like it is available.

Comment: Thats what I was scared of someone confirming.  Thanks though